# What is the point of nested factories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I just don't know what they're for. Before I thought they were for populating foreign keys easily but now I see that's not the case.

```
# User attributes: id, name, password
factory :user_0, class: User do
    id 0
    name "Jimmy"
    password "Jimson"
end

# Status attributes: id, user_id, content
factory :user_0_statuses, class: Status do
    association :user, factory: :user_0

    factory :user_0_status_0 do
        id 0
        content "noo"
    end
    factory :user_0_status_1 do
        id 1
        content "yees"
    end
end
```

When :user_0_status_0 and :user_0_status_1 factories are `.create`d in a spec, I thought that this factory setup would create the following in the database (note the status' user_id entries.):

```
users    
id | name  | password
0  | Jimmy | Jimson

statuses
id | user_id | content
0  | 0       | noo
1  | 0       | yees
```

But instead it creates this:

```
users    
id | name  | password
0  | Jimmy | Jimson
0  | Jimmy | Jimson

statuses
id | user_id | content
0  | nil     | noo
1  | nil     | yees
```

Basically, a brand new user based on the user_0 factory is created for every nested status factory, and the user_id of the status isn't set at all. How is this behaviour useful?

I just can't see any use at all regarding nested factories. What are they, and the association method, for?

Comment: Please use meaningful variable names instead of `user_0_something`, hard to know your intention.

Comment: I'm not testing anything, all I care about in this question is the impact of nested tables on the transitional database entries that are created.

Comment: I know you are not testing something. I just have difficulty to understand the question with such variable names, I don't know what they are for.

Comment: user_0_status_0 is a status belonging to user_0 (through the user_id). user_0_status_1 is a second status belonging to user_0.

Comment: Factory is about model, it should not be specific about certain object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a factory is nested inside another factory definition, it inherits the attributes defined in the parent factory. If you had a User factory, you could nest an "admin_user" factory inside of it that would have all the base user characteristics plus whatever makes an user an admin without having to redefine the base attributes twice.

(slightly unrelated: I'm not sure if setting the primary key (is Status is an ActiveRecord class) is a reliable practice, and I'd advise finding another way to solve that problem.)